# List <ul> position at top

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a `<ul>` list with a specific width of 50%, it should show side by side, but for some reason if I have more text (more than 1 line), it puts margin at the top of second LI. Please take a look at the following screenshot..

[image]

Below is my current code..

```
        .checklist {
          list-style-type: none;
          display:block !important;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        .checklist li {
            margin-bottom:4px;
            width: 40%;
            margin-top:0 !important;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        .checklist .icon-holder {
            margin-top:1px;
            background:#444;
            font-size:11px;
            line-height:11px;
            color:#fff;
            width:65px;
            height:50px;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
            float:left;
            display: table;
        }
        .icon-holder i {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
        .item-content {
            margin-top:0 !important;;
            margin-left:80px;
        }
        .item-content h3 {
            margin:0;
        }
```

here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/92458m8v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default vertical alignment of inline elements is baseline (which is what you're seeing). Change it by adding `vertical-align:top` to your list item rules:

```
.checklist li {
    margin-bottom:4px;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top:0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/92458m8v/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. It worked. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can set `vertical-align` to `<li>` to adjust the `inline` positions

**CSS**

```
.checklist li {
   margin-bottom:4px;
   width: 40%;
   margin-top:0 !important;
   display:inline-block;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/92458m8v/2/)**

Comment: Thanks. Its working.